# SetError Icon overlaps other edittext icons

Tags: java, android, xml, android-styles

**setError** icon overlaps my other icon in the edittext

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_separator_2"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/custom_show_hide_password_black"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/acc_password"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_1D1D1D"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_5A5D63"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="Password" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In this image Eye icon and Exclamation mark are overlapped , i want it to be side by side first showerror message icon and then eye icon , is there any way to do it.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Please add your layout.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Since you are having your `app:passwordToggleDrawable` in `TextInputLayout` you should call `setError()` also in `textInputLayout`. Please refer the code below

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout_password);
textInputLayout.setError("Password is empty");
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to call this function.

```
passwordTxtInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout_password);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    if (etPassword != null) {
        etPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                passwordTxtInputLayout.setEndIconVisible(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

and call this function whenever the password length is less than and equal to zero

```
passwordTxtInputLayout.setEndIconVisible(false);
```

Make sure this function should be called before calling setError otherwise eyeIcon will be disable.